# How to solve Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Permission denied?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, atom-editor

I am trying to install Atom code editor on Ubuntu subsystem. However, I am currently facing this error after doing sudo apt-get install atom.

This is the error I am facing currently:
Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Permission denied.

As seen in the image below, it seems like I have to input something to end the command which I do not know how I can solve it.

[image]

Please advise. Thank you!

Comment: Any solution? Please update here, I too facing same issue

Comment: @Shakthifuture Still facing the same issue... I ended up installing sublime

Comment: I have resolved this issue, I help you out. Let me know how you installed Ubuntu on your machine using WSL on top of the windows?

Comment: It may not have all the necessary privileges, try `docker run --cap-add=SYS_ADMIN`. Check this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/63219871) for more info

Answer (score 0):

try `atom --no-sandbox`

or `sudo atom --no-sandbox`