# Docker-Compose: order of cap_drop and cap_add?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, linux-capabilities

The [docker compose file reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#cap_add-cap_drop) describes the `cap_add` and `cap_drop` elements in a rather terse fashion:

> Add or drop container capabilities. See man 7 capabilities for a full list.

Do these elements have an order, that is, add first, then drop? Or does the order matter (is this supported in YAML at all for dictionaries?)?

What happens when one of `cap_add` or `cap_drop` contains `ALL`?

I'm aware of the Docker Linux default set of capabilities, defined in https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/oci/caps/defaults.go#L4.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

After diving around the moby source code, I finally located [TweakCapabilities()](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/a1f6a705225eedcb55fe6dac7dec0b9870330d78/oci/caps/utils.go#L83): it takes the two sets of capabilities to add and to drop, enforcing the following scheme below; thus works in docker-compose.yaml where YAML doesn't define an order for the `cap_add` and `cap_drop` keys. The first matching item below will terminate the list.

- container is `privileged: true`: ignore `cap_add` and `cap_drop` completely, return **all available capabilities** instead.
- both `cap_add` and `cap_drop` are **empty**: return the default Docker set of capabilities.
- `cap_add` contains `ALL`: return all capabilities **minus** the capabilities listed in `cap_drop` (ignores `ALL` in the latter).
- `cap_drop` contains `ALL`: return the capabilities from `cap_add` only, ignoring any Docker default capabilities.
- default: first drop all capabilites from the default set listed in `cap_drop`, then add the capabilities in `cap_add`, and finally return the result.

If I'm not mistaken this can be also represented in a more accessible manner as follows...

[image: cap_add/cap_drop]

| `privileged: true` |
| --- |
| **ALL capabilities**: ignores `cap_add` and `cap_drop` (boss mode) |

|  | no `cap_add` | `cap_add: ['CAP_A']` | `cap_add: ['ALL']` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **no `cap_drop`** | default capabilities | default + `CAP_A` | **ALL capabilities** |
| **`cap_drop: ['CAP_Z']`** | default -`CAP_Z` | default -`CAP_Z` +`CAP_A` | ALL -`CAP_Z` |
| **`cap_drop: ['ALL']`** | **NO capabilities** | `CAP_A` | **ALL capabilities** |

In the end, there's only the following two "deterministic" combinations that always include `cap_drop: ALL` and that follow the line of least privilege:

[image: cap-drop]

|  | no `cap_add` | `cap_add: ['CAP_A']` |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |
| **`cap_drop: ['ALL']`** | **NO capabilities** | `CAP_A` |  |

Comment: Thanks for the anwser. Just one comment. It is a good practice to share the permanent link for TweakCapabilities() to avoid pointing to the wrong place: https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/ad9d70b0e6833b746eecccc08a17459ba8bb31c4/oci/caps/utils.go#L83

Comment: somehow I got the wrong link, but that's fixed now; of course, this should have been a perma link right from the beginning.